# Angular - Initialization and Data Sharing Issue between Modules in Module Federation

Tags: angular, module, angular-module-federation

Currently, I'm facing a challenge in my architecture based on Module Federation with Angular 17. I have two modules, the main SHELL module and a flexibility-view module, which is accessed directly from the shell.

Before rendering the table in flexibility-view, I need to make a call to get the roles associated with the user. I've tried various approaches, but encountered difficulties.

I attempted to use APP_INITIALIZER in the ApplicationConfig of the flexibility-view module, but it seems this solution doesn't work when accessing flexibility-view directly from the shell.

Here's how I configured APP_INITIALIZER in the ApplicationConfig of the flexibility-view module:

```
provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (startup: StartupGrantService) => () => startup.initLoggedUser(),
      multi: true,
      deps: [StartupGrantService],
    }
```

Additionally, I experimented with using APP_INITIALIZER in the ApplicationConfig of the shell, and the function is successfully executed. However, the populated User object cannot be used in flexibility-view.

For instance, if I include the following code in flexibility-view, the object appears empty:

```
readonly grantService = inject(SERVICE);
```

I kindly ask for suggestions on how to handle this situation in Module Federation. Should I manage initialization and data sharing in the flexibility-view module or in the SHELL module? And how can I ensure that the User object is accessible and usable in flexibility-view?

Thank you in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Integration:

I'm encountering a problem with my Angular application using Module Federation. I have a SHELL module that, upon initialization (using APP_INITIALIZER), fetches user roles through a REST API and loads a microfrontend on its route. Here's how the SHELL is configured:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation()),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (startup: StartupGrantService) => () => startup.initLoggedUser(),
      multi: true,
      deps: [StartupGrantService],
    }
  ]
};
```

The webpack configuration for the SHELL is as follows:

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },
});
```

The webpack configuration for the flexibility-view module is as follows:

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'flexibility-view',
  exposes: {
    './Component': './projects/flexibility-view/src/app/app.component.ts',
  },
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },
});
```

Our requirement is that when the SHELL loads the remote module in its routes, it should also pass the user information to the remote module.

Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this within the context of Module Federation? Should I handle it in the SHELL module or the flexibility-view module? Additionally, how can I ensure that user information is passed successfully when loading the remote module?

Thank you for any assistance or suggestions.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducable example on github? Looks like you're accessing different types from different js modules but it's hard to tell exactly

Comment: I have updated the text in the hope that it is clearer.